# Open "Something.app" with Rosetta using Terminal

Tags: terminal, applications, rosetta

Let's say I wanted a command line function to open up Xcode (or really, any app) under Rosetta.

For command line utilities, I can use `arch -x86_64 UTILITY`, but that doesn't really extend to full applications. Are there any launch arguments that I can pass to `open` in order to force a Rosetta instance?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while searching on how to do the same thing for my own app so I thought to post what worked for me in case others are also facing the same issue.

Not a command line argument per se but you can add `LSArchitecturePriority` to Info.plist.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsarchitecturepriority):

> Use this key to prioritize the execution of a specific architecture in
> a universal binary. This key contains an array of strings, with each
> string specifying the name of a supported architecture. The order of
> the strings in the array represents your preference for executing the
> app. For example, if you specify the x86_64 architecture first for a
> universal app, the system runs that app under Rosetta translation on
> Apple silicon.

So just add

```
<key>LSArchitecturePriority</key>
<array>
    <string>x86_64</string>
</array>
```

to your Info.plist to open with Rosetta by default just by using `open -a example.app`.

Note: As stated in the documentation, it only works for universal binary so to check if your app is a universal binary, run

```
lipo -archs example.app/Contents/MacOS/exec
```

and if the output is either

```
x86_64 arm64
```

or

```
x86_64 arm64e
```

it means that your app is a universal binary.